# Observer Pattern in networking

Tags: java, networking, client-server, observer-pattern

I can't figure out how observer pattern is used on the client-server program in java. Please who can give me information about this .

Comment: you need to elaborate the issue.

Comment: in the book is written that , observer pattern is used in notification handling on the client-server , but i cant find any code example . How it can implemented in code ?